# Hiding a private key in a Swift application

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm putting together a weather application that fetches weather data from the Dark Sky API using calls similar to the following: `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/_My_Private_API_Key_/51.3,-1.0`.

Although it's a small risk, what is the best way to store my private API key in the application in order to prevent someone extracting the key and obtaining weather data at my expense?  (For example, by using it in their own app which goes on to sell millions while at the same time bankrupting me and turning my family out on to the streets.)

Comment: Such a simple answer and obvious too (after someone mentions it).  Thanks.

Comment: Are you sending the private key down at some point? If not, then no point in storing in the keychain, since it will already need to be a value in your code, in that case, just leave it as-is (e.g. a macro).